# $\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(f(\frac{x}{\sqrt{n}})\right)^n = e^{\frac{ax^2}{2}}$

Tags: real-analysis, limits

Let $f$ be a real-valued differential function on $\mathbb{R}$ such that the second derivative $f''(0)$ at the origin exists with $f(0)=f'(0)=0$ and $f''(0)=a$. Show that 
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(f(\frac{x}{\sqrt{n}})\right)^n = e^{\frac{ax^2}{2}}
$$
for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$.

I've tried using Taylor's theorem. So

$$
f(\frac{x}{\sqrt{n}}) = f(0) + f'(0)\frac{x}{\sqrt{n}} + \frac{1}{2}f''(0)\frac{x^2}{n} + R(\frac{x}{\sqrt{n}}) = \frac{ax^2}{2n} + R(\frac{x}{\sqrt{n}}).
$$

I get suck after this part. Any help please?

Comment: You did not state any property of $R$. What do you know about $R$?

Comment: Well, $R$ is $o(\frac{x^2}{n})$.

Comment: Take $x=0$. Then the LHS is $0$, while the RHS is $1$. You probably want $f(0)=1$.

Comment: Yeah, I noticed that. That's the statement I was given. I'm guessing the correct statement would be for all $x \in \mathbb{R} \setminus \{0\}$.

Answer (score 1):

You need $f$ to be nonzero on some small interval $[-\epsilon,\epsilon]$ (e.g. $a\neq 0)$. Using your Taylor expansion, write the inside of the limit as:

$$\exp(n\log(f(x/\sqrt{n}))=\exp(n\log(a^2/2n+o(x^2/n))$$

Now factor out $a^2/2n$ from the logarithm, simplify and then proceed to evaluate the limit.

Comment: I tried this as well, but I don't see what factoring out that term does for me. Using $\ln(ab) = \ln(a) + \ln(b)$ you mean? That doesn't seem to help.